# Invalid JSON in tag schema

Tags: json, schema, shopify, liquid

Hey guys I am really new to shopify. and trying to learn liquid. I am getting an invalid JSON tag in schema/ and I am not quite sure where it is. I am just trying to have 4 basic blocks that you can add to a section with a image and a title underneath. I don't have the content block made right now because I can't get the image one to work in the first place.

```
{% for block in section.blocks %}
  <div class="grid-item" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
  {% case block.type %}
  {% when 'image' %}
    <img src="{{ block.settings.image | img_url }}">

</div>
  {% when 'text' %}
    {{ block.settings.content }}
  {% endcase %}
{% endfor %}

{% schema %}
  {
    {
    "blocks": [
      {
       "name": "Service",
       "limit": 4
       "settings": [
          {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "image",
          "label": "image"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  }
{% endschema %}
```

Once again, Like I said, I am really new to all of this so any point in the right direction or help would be crazy awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

missing a comma after your limit: 4?

Comment: I think that may have been it. I have since moved on to a different part of the site. but I remember finding something small like that that was the fix. Thanks!